# Order of entire function $f + g$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am given a different definition of a finite order of an entire function from the one given in the link [Order of $\frac{f}{g}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663080/order-of-fracfg). My definition is that an entire function $f$ has finite order $\rho$ if
$$\rho = \inf \{a : |f(z)| \le \exp(|z|^a) \quad \forall |z| \ge r, \text{ some } r > 0 \}.$$
This is equivalent to saying, letting $\epsilon > 0$, we have $|f(z)|< \exp(|z|^{\rho + \epsilon})$ for all $z$ with $|z|$ sufficiently large.

I would like to use these to show that if $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$, $\rho$ are of finite orders of entire functions $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_1 + f_2$ respectively, then $\rho \le \max(\rho_1, \rho_2)$.

Let $M(r) = \max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$ and $\rho_0 = \max(\rho_1, \rho_2)$. Then for $r = |z|$ sufficiently large,
$$M(r) < \exp(|z|^{\rho_1 + \epsilon}) + \exp(|z|^{\rho_2 + \epsilon}) \le 2 \exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + \epsilon}).$$
I'm getting stuck at this step. What should I do next? I'm thinking of writing $2 = e^{\log 2}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
2 \exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + \epsilon})=2\exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + \epsilon}(1-|z|^\epsilon)) \exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + 2\epsilon})\le\exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + 2\epsilon})
$$
if $|z|$ is large enough. In fact, it is enough to have
$$
|z|^{\rho_0 + \epsilon}(1-|z|^\epsilon)\le\log\frac12,
$$
and this is possible because $|z|^{\rho_0 + \epsilon}(1-|z|^\epsilon)\to-\infty$ as $|z|\to\infty$.

Comment: Why do we have the first equality? I thought $\exp(|z|^{-\epsilon/2}) \exp(|z|^{\rho_0 + 3\epsilon/2}) = \exp(|z|^{-\epsilon/2} + |z|^{\rho_0 + 3\epsilon/2})$.

Comment: Right. I have edited the answer.