# Question about the order of entire function $f+g$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

My question is based on this old question : [Order of entire function $f + g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020897/order-of-entire-function-f-g). I try to better understand the inequality we get for the order of $f+g$. It is obvious that there are two cases. The one where $\rho=\max \lbrace \lambda _{1}, \lambda _{2}\rbrace$ and the one where $\rho <\max \lbrace \lambda _{1}, \lambda _{2}\rbrace$. I have already managed to prove the first case, but I am looking for examples for the second. Can anyone help me find an example that shows the second case (for $f\neq 0$)?

Comment: You mean something like $f(z) = e^z$ and $g(z) = -e^z$? Or $g(z) = z-e^z$ if you don't want the sum to be identically zero?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! Just a question : for $f(z)=e^{z}$ and $g(z)=z−e^{z}$, $\lambda _{f}=1$ ,  $\lambda _{g} =?$ and $\lambda _{f+g}=\lambda _{z}  = ?$. Because I don't know the order for $f(z)=z$

Comment: The order of $e^z$ is one, the order of $z$ is zero.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f, g$ are entire functions with $\lambda_f \ne \lambda_g$ then the “order inequality”
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \lambda_{f+g} \le \max(\lambda_f, \lambda_g) 
$$
becomes an equality:
$$
 \lambda_{f+g} = \max(\lambda_f, \lambda_g) \, .
$$

*Proof:* Assume that $\lambda_g < \lambda_f$. Then $\lambda_{f+g} \le \lambda_f$ and
$$
 \lambda_f = \lambda_{f+g-g} \le \max(\lambda_{f+g}, \lambda_g)
 \le \max(\lambda_f, \lambda_g) = \lambda_f \\
\implies\max(\lambda_{f+g}, \lambda_g) = \lambda_f \\
\implies \lambda_{f+g} = \lambda_f \, .
$$

---

This can be used to construct examples where $(*)$ is a strict inequality. Choose entire functions $f, h$ with $\lambda_h < \lambda_f$ and set $g = h-f$. Then $\lambda_f = \lambda_g$ and
$$
 \lambda_{f+g} = \lambda_h < \lambda_f = \max(\lambda_f, \lambda_g) \, .
$$

A simple example is $f(z) =e^z$ and $h(z) = z$, which have order $1$ and $0$, respectively.